# Learning how to properly reference to a struct field when using scanf (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, struct

I've made this struct

```c
struct dadosPessoais
{
    char nome[60];
    char end[60];
    char cidade[60];
    char estado[3];
    int cep;
};
typedef struct dadosPessoais dadosPessoais
```

Also, I've declared these variable and pointer

```c
dadosPessoais dp[4], *dpp;
```

What I'm currently trying to do is receive some data from user and using *dpp pointer in order to store this data within dp[] variable. To do it, I've made this loop structure

```c
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    dpp = &dp[i];
    printf("-- Dados da %da pessoa --\n", i + 1);
    printf("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", dpp->nome);
    getchar();
    printf("Endereço: ");
    scanf("%s", dpp->end);
    getchar();
    printf("Cidade: ");
    scanf("%s", dpp->cidade);
    getchar();
    printf("Estado: ");
    scanf("%s", dpp->estado);
    getchar();
    printf("Cep: ");
    scanf("%d", dpp->cep);
    getchar();
    system("clear");
}
```

I know that using something like `dpp->field` is not correct when using scanf, since the arrow operator (->) is used to return a struct field value by using the address of that struct variable and it's not used to return the struct field address itself. But if I try to use something like `dpp.field` it still doesn't work, what is confusing since it supposed to mean something like `&dp[index].field`, right? I still doesn't figured out how to solve this problem...

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.  A well enabled compiler would complain about `scanf("%d", dpp->cep);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `dpp = &dp[i];` is executed, `dpp` points to an instance of the `struct dadosPessoais`. Then `dpp->cep` refers to the `cep` member of that `struct`, and `&dpp->cep` is the address of that member. So, to pass the address of the `cep` member to `scanf`, pass `&dpp->cep`.

When using `scanf` with `%s`, you should pass the address of the first character in the array. So, for `dpp->nome`, you could pass `&dpp->nome[0]`.

However, since `nome` is an array, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element when you use it in an expression.<sup>1</sup> So, you can use pass `dpp->nome` to `scanf`, and it will be the same as passing `&dpp->nome[0]`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This automatic conversion does not occur when the array is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of the unary `&` operator (which takes the address), or is a string literal used to initialize an array. Note in particular that `&array` and `array` are pointers, but the type of `&array` is “pointer to array,” whereas `array`, after automatic conversion, is a pointer to an element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it should be scanf("%s", dpp->nome). Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
     char a[10];
};

int main() {
     struct test new_struct_array[1];
     struct test * ptr = &new_struct_array[0];
     scanf("%s", ptr->a);
     printf("%s", ptr->a);
     return 0;
}
```

In C, arrays will point to the memory address of their first element. That is why when you do something like this:

```
char nome[10];
scanf("%s", nome);  // works
scanf("%s", &nome); // does not
```

`nome` is already a reference to the start of the array.

Comment: This does not speak to the `cep` member and does not address OP’s lack of understanding about referring to structure members and their addresses.